# How I can open Internet Explore only with Selenium driver IE. (No use Microsfot Edge)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

I need to make test case with python in offline terminal. That terminal only have Internet Explore, don't have microsoft Edge.

For that in my terminal I tried to use only Internet Explorer, but the selenium open Edge with IE mode, I don't want it.

Example:
[image: Selenium open Microsofot Edge with IE Mode]

How to set up the code to open only Internet explore?

Driver version: IE 4.8.1.0
Explorer version: 22H2

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



#CONFIGURACION
s=Service(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\programacion\CLARO\drivers\IEDriverServer.exe")

#ie_options = webdriver.IeOptions()
#ie_options.attach_to_edge_chrome = True
#ie_options.edge_executable_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
#driver = webdriver.Ie(service=s, options=ie_options)
driver = webdriver.Ie(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
#PERSONALIZACION
driver.get("http://python.org")
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Selenium is no longer support standalone IE according to [this](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/internet_explorer/).